# Error while downloading packages from npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm, ionic-framework

I'm a getting a network error while downloading package from NPM: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuTHU.png). How can I fix it?

```
D:\\ionic\\abc\\abc\>npm install @capacitor/push-notifications

npm ERR! code EPROTO

npm ERR! syscall write

npm ERR! errno EPROTO

npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@capacitor%2fpush-notifications failed, reason: write EPROTO 18380000:error:0A000410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:c:\\ws\\deps\\openssl\\openssl\\ssl\\record\\rec_layer_s3.c:1586:SSL alert number 40

npm ERR!

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\\Users\\91933\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\\_logs\\2023-10-28T10_16_43_472Z-debug-0.log
```

I downloaded the lastest version of `node` and `npm`, but it's not working.

Comment: Are you in a corporate network where something is blocking or interfering with the SSL traffic from your machine?

Answer (score 0):

Perform below steps:

```
npm cache clean --force

npm cache verify

npm install @capacitor/push-notifications
```

Also try with sudo once if you are using mac